# remove required from field in child model yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I have a main model and it has a field rules:

```
class User extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'users';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['username', 'email'], 'required'],
        ];
    }
}
```

I must say right away that I cannot make changes to this model, I can make all changes only in the next model that will be inherited from this:

```
class UserForm extends User
{
    public function rules(): array
    {
        return array_merge(
            parent::rules(),
            [ 
                ['username', 'safe', 'skipOnEmpty' => true],
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

The bottom line is that in the first model the username field is required, but now I need to make it so that when filling out the form it is empty, and when saving the value of the email field is copied to the username field.

For copying I use the function:

```
public function beforeSave($insert)
    {
        if (empty($this->username)) {
            $this->username = $this->email;
        }

        return parent::beforeSave($insert);
    }
```

But due to the fact that the username field is required, nothing is saved for me, what I did in the child model does not work. How can I make a field optional without editing the first model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't replace the rule by adding another. If you define rules like that, the result is that both, `required` and `safe` rule are applied for `username` field.

You have to find the `required` rule in rules definition array and remove `username` from attributes the rule applies to.
It can be easy if you know that the rule definition will always be in specific position. For example if it's always the first rule in parent model:

```php
public function rules()
{
    $rules = parent::rules();
    // the array diff is used to remove only 'username' field from list of attributes
    $rules[0][0] = array_diff($rules[0][0], ['username']);        
    return $rules;
}
```

If you don't know the position of `required` rule, you will need to use some cycle to find it. For example like this:

```php
foreach ($rules as $rule) {
    if (
        $rule[1] == 'required'
        && (
            (is_array($rule[0]) && in_array('username', $rule[0]))
            || (is_string($rule[0]) && $rule[0] == 'username')
        )
    ) {
       // rule found
    }  
}
```

But there is **another possible solution** to your problem. Instead of copying the value of `email` field in `beforeSave()` callback you can copy it in [`beforeValidate()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-activerecord#beforeValidate()-detail) callback. That way when the `username` field is validated it will already have the value of email field and it will pass validation.

Answer (score 1):

You could bypass the required validation by adding a where clause in your rule:

```
[['username', 'email'], 'required', 'when' => function() { return false; }],
```

Since the function always returns false, the validator is never aplied.

Comment: does not help, I cannot edit the User model, and if this is added to the UserForm, then nothing changes

Comment: Have you tried to omit the `array_merge` and write the whole rules on your own? Or you could use `array_replace_recursive` instead of `array_merge`.